# 新しいバッジの和訳: Lifejacket / Lifeboat

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, バッジ

Stack Overflow Blog: [Adios to Unfriendly Badges: Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) (2019/06/18)

上のブログ記事に書いてあるように、バッジ [閑古鳥](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) と [仇取り](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) が廃止され、新しいバッジ [Lifejacket](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/126/lifejacket) と [Lifeboat](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/127/lifeboat) が追加されていることに気付きました。

このバッジ名の和訳をしたいです。どのような名前が良いでしょうか？

Comment: 直訳だと`救命ボート`と`救命胴衣`ですかね？「助けを必要としています」みたいな感じでしょうか？

Comment: 訳は変に捻るより今回は直訳でよさそうです。バッジ獲得の条件としては「スコアの低い質問を回答によってプラス(の印象)に変えてあげた」結果もらえるみたいです。

Comment: cubick さんの意見に+1。取得方法から考えても他の訳は思いつかないですかね。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

合ってるか不安ですが、バッジの名称と説明の翻訳案です。

---

**救命胴衣** (`Lifejacket`)

> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more.

スコアが -2 以下の質問に、スコアが 5 以上の回答を行い、質問のスコアを 2 以上にした。

---

**救命ボート** (`Lifeboat`)

> Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes on to receive a score of 3 or more

スコアが -3 以下の質問に、スコアが 20 以上の回答を行い、質問のスコアを 3 以上にした。

Comment: 他のバッジの説明に数値のフォーマットを合わせました。

Comment: Traducir でこの翻訳を採用しました。暫くすると反映されるはずです。ありがとうございました！